# Error with calling stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have the following c# code to call stored procedure `testproc`, but when I run this application it says that it could not find stored procedure testproc.

This is my c# code behind to call the stored procedure:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "data source='example.com';user id='sa';password='password';persist security info=False;initial catalog=Test;Connect Timeout=100; Min Pool Size=100; Max Pool Size=500";
con.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("testproc",con );
SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
//sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Id,Name1,ZipCode,StreetName,StreetNumber,State1,Lat,Lng,Keyword, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (12.925432/57.2958) ) * COS(  (Lat/57.2958)  ) * COS( ( Lng/57.2958 ) - (77.5940171/57.2958) ) + SIN( 12.925432/57.2958 ) * SIN(  Lat/57.2958  ) ) ) AS distance FROM Business_Details where( (StreetName like '%jayanagar%')and (Keyword like '%plumbing%' ))ORDER BY distance;";
//sqlda.CommandText = "select * from business where(( distance<'" + radius + "' )and (StreetName like '%" + streetname + "%')and (Keyword like '%" + keyword1 + "%' )) order by distance";
//com.CommandText = "testproc ";
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lat1",SqlDbType.Float,50,lat1));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lng1",SqlDbType.Float,50,lng1));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@radius1",SqlDbType.Int,10,radius1));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@streetname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, streetname));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@keyword1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, keyword1)); 
com.Parameters[0].Value = lat1;
com.Parameters[1].Value = lng1;
com.Parameters[2].Value = radius1;
com.Parameters[3].Value = streetname;
com.Parameters[4].Value = keyword1;
try
{                
    sqlda.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    con.Close();
}
```

This is my stored procedure I have written in sql server. It runs successfully in SQL server

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[tesproc]    Script Date: 09/01/2010 13:00:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tesproc]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @a float, @b float, @d int,@s varchar(50),@k varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select Id, Name1,ZipCode,StreetName,StreetNumber,State1,Lat,Lng , ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (@a/57.2958) ) * COS(  (Lat/57.2958)  ) * COS( ( Lng/57.2958 ) - (@b /57.2958) )  + SIN( @a/57.2958 ) * SIN(  Lat/57.2958  ) ) ) as distance from business_details where (( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (@a/57.2958) ) * COS(  (Lat/57.2958)  ) * COS( ( Lng/57.2958 ) - (@b /57.2958) )  + SIN( @a/57.2958 ) * SIN(  Lat/57.2958  ) ) )<@d and StreetName like '%'+ @s + '%' and Keyword like '%'+ @k +'%')
END
```

Comment: I know it's a local db, and it looks like a testing password, but you should always be careful posting your connection details. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion from next i will not post any connection details .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway your code should look like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlComamnd command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = commandText;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add("@lat1", SqlDbType.Float,50, lat1).Value = lat1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@lng1", SqlDbType.Float,50, lng1).Value = lng1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@radius1", SqlDbType.Int,10, radius1).Value = radius1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@streetname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, streetname).Value = streetname;
    command.Parameters.Add("@keyword1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, keyword1).Value = keyword1;

    connection .Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = neq SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        adapter.Fill(ds);                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your ALTER statement calls it `tesproc`,  but your SQL command calls it `testproc`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,I am not able to track your answer please can you be more clear

Comment: Your stored procedure is called `tesproc` with only one T.  The following line has testproc spelled with TWO T's:  `SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("testproc",con );`.  One of these is a typographical error.  I can't be much more clear than that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , sorry from my side i did carefully notice that their in spelling mistake .

Answer (score 5):

Check your spelling, your procedure is called

```
[dbo].[tesproc]
```

and your code is calling

```
SqlCommand("testproc",con );
```

You can also add parameters using

```
Parameters.AddWithValue(string parameterName, Object value)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx

if you wanted to :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did not notice that spelling mistake at all
thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this bulky code

```
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lat1",SqlDbType.Float,50,lat1));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lng1",SqlDbType.Float,50,lng1));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@radius1",SqlDbType.Int,10,radius1));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@streetname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, streetname));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@keyword1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, keyword1)); 
com.Parameters[0].Value = lat1;
com.Parameters[1].Value = lng1;
com.Parameters[2].Value = radius1;
com.Parameters[3].Value = streetname;
com.Parameters[4].Value = keyword1;
```

**And you are assigning value again to parameters**

use `AddWithValue` method to add parameter to command

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lat1", lat1));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lng1", lng1));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@radius1", radius1));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@streetname", streetname));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyword1", keyword1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ,I made changes to the code 
com.Parameters.AddwithValue("@lat1",lat1); its helpfull thank you.